# Why is this marked a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

This question was marked a duplicate: [Tried to install wireless driver and now terminal and update manager no longer work either](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420587/tried-to-install-wireless-driver-and-now-terminal-and-update-manager-no-longer-w)

However, the link given, [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx) contains several answers that are just plain incorrect. How is this brand new user supposed to wade through 38 answers and decide which one or ones are correct and which are just plain wrong? He already tried bcmwl-kernel-source as suggested in the alleged answer and it didn't work! It didn't work because it is just wrong for his 14e4:4312 device.

Please help me understand, if it is indeed possible to understand Broadcom wireless. Even better, please un-duplicate his question and let me answer him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because is the wrong duplicated. OP is trying to do Y but finds X problem. The duplicated answers his Y concern but doesn't solve X problem which block him. The correct way is fixing up the mess and see if OP has running apt/dpkg somewhere, otherwise restart the system.

Comment: I understand that completely! However, it is still marked a duplicate so neither you nor I can tell him what he was referred to is just plain wrong and what to do instead.

Comment: @chili555 check my comment on the question, I already find out the issue and easy to fix, but be aware that those kind of questions normally makes us waste a lot of effort to answer since OP is most of the time clueless.

Comment: Indeed they are. So why do we refer them to an answer we know is wrong and convert them from clueless to frustrated and mad???

Comment: @chili555 ask that to the one that did the closure.

Comment: You are quite correct. It takes extra effort to answer the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the initial problem was getting BCM4311 working, which is address in great detail there.  If there's a problem with those methods, you could bring it up in comments to "fix" the answer.  Then we have a great answer on getting wireless working.

Networking being in an inconsistent state would cause the rest of that question.  It could just "go away" after wireless is fixed, so basically it turns in to reference these answers to get the wireless up and we can ask again or reopen a revised question.

That's just how I read it.

Comment: The procedure to install the driver for 14e4:4312 is indeed covered very well at the link given. It is, however, quite incorrect.

Comment: Then the answer should be improved.

Comment: I shall begin immediately to read and edit all 38 answers.

Comment: The top voted two would be enough.  Please understand the voting system is in place for a reason.